# how to use select2-removed of select2 in angularjs for triggering event when input is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select2

I am using ui-select2 but is facing an issue while using allowClear: true. 
allowClear is working as intended but need to fire an event when the input is cleared. 
I tried implementing it through $watch but no success. Is there a way to use select2-removed function in angularjs.

```
<select ui-select2="timeConfig" ng-model="time" data-placeholder="{{TIME.placeholder}}">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in TIME.options" value="{{option.value}}">
{{option.title}}</option>
        </select>
```

// in controller

```
 $scope.timeConfig = {
    allowClear : true
    }

 $scope.$watch('time', function(newVal,oldVal) {
    if(newVal=='') {
        console.log("Value is changed to clear");
    }
    console.log("Changing and making new request");
    }, true);
```

When I click clear button $watch is not fired (value in model remains unchanged)

Comment: what does the clear button do?

Comment: it clears the selected option in select2 to placeholder.

Comment: please include the button markup and js, too.

Comment: select2 adds the clear button on its own, small x(cross) whenever each item is selected.

Comment: i see. can you create a live demo demonstrating this issue? (e.g. using [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option for select2 events (you can see it at source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/blob/master/src/select2.js)

Please, look at simple demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/FDrgZncCEajRulrHmjz4?p=preview, your code work pretty well, when I click on 'clear', I can see 'Value is changed to clear' message at log.

May be problem at your other code?

Comment: thanks for the plnkr... helped me debugging the code. :)